# Force "just for me" during software installation

Tags: windows-10

I have a variety of software that I use (e.g., iTunes) only very rarely.

Can I force the "just for me" option when installing under a specific user so that my primary user account generally runs leaner and meaner (i.e., so that background processes/services are only run per user).

(e.g., iTunes related software and services would only load if I logged in with the specially created 'iTunes' user, and if it worked nicely then all development software loads only with dev login, etc)

Comment: This is indeed possible.  All you have to do is not run the installer as an Administrator.

Comment: You could change the install directory to some directory under `%USERPROFILE%` (for example, `C:\Users\your_user\Programs`).  Afterwards, you can then go and recursively change ownership of the program's files.

Comment: To clarify, is 'not an administrator' simply the default win 10 'standard' account or do I need to look at group policies and tweak things?

Comment: @Ramhound running as non-admin means that it prompts you saying you need admin permission to install.  When I don't give permission, it fails to install.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: On the installer, change the install directory to one on *YOUR ACCOUNT*, it will appear ONLY on your account.

Comment: Afraid not - this just results in apps with permission problems the few times I've tried it.

Comment: Which application did you try it with, if you don't mind answering, @Mikey-T-K-. It has never failed for me.